# How to install gradle-5.5.1-all.zip in android studio manually?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I want to install gradle 5.5.1 (from local) on Android Studio 3.4.2, for this download grandle [gradle-5.5.1-all.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) and on the "gradle-wrapper.properties" file change this:

```
distributionUrl=file:///E:/Downloads/gradle-5.5.1-all.zip
```

and on "build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1'
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter() 
  }
}
```

but when want to make the project I have get this error:

```
  ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:
```

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.jar

```
Required by:
   project :
Open File
```

But there is no file at these URLs, whats wrong?

Comment: The version of Gradle used by Android Studio is controlled by the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your first code snippet. The `classpath` line in the second code snippet is not for Gradle, but for the Android Gradle Plugin, which is a separate piece of software, obtained from one of the repositories that you have listed in the `repositories` closure in the `buildscript` closure.

Comment: one can also install it globally. eg. in `/opt/gradle` and not use the wrapper at all... however, the wrapper is pretty convenient, when a new version of Android Studio demands a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace this wrongful line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1'
```

with a version of build-tools, which actually exists:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```